# Symfony: doctrine:build --all --and-load Break down to individual commands?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

With my Symfony projects now, for a while I've been using the following command to drop my database, create everything and reload all my fixtures...

```
./symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

What I'm wondering, is what individual `./symfony doctrine:whatever` commands does this break down to and in what order? Like if I wanted to execute each individual command one-at-a-time to accomplish the same result, what are the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is here: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks
Here you can read all task documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the source of sfDoctrineBuildTask would tell you the following:

```
doctrine:drop-db
doctrine:build-db
doctrine:build-model
doctrine:build-forms
doctrine:build-filters
doctrine:build-sql
doctrine:insert-sql
doctrine:data-load
```

Comment: Doh! Didn't think about looking there. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting an error with the `data-load` step at the end. Don't get the error with the `build --all --and-load`... something is missing I think.